# Is there any certificate manager available by OS in Ubuntu (i.e. Windows Certificate Manager)?

Tags: software-recommendation, certificates

Currently I am working with Digital Signing.
I am aware that Windows is having "Windows Cert. Manager" provided by Windows OS to manage certificates.

Is there any default Certificate Manager available in Ubuntu for managing trusted certificates?

I have searched on this topic much but couldn't find anything concrete.
Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On Kubuntu 19.10 there is Kleopatra. I did not try on other version.